# C++ SFML Collison Detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml, 2d-games

I am trying to make a game where you gave to dodge the incoming box (thing). I don't know how to code a quick and easy collision detection using if statements.
I have tried to code this at "//collision detection". I want it so that if the arrow (player) is touching the box the game closes.

Main Menu.h

```
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace sf;
 using namespace std;
 #pragma once

 class main_menu
 {
 public:
    void startmenu(RenderWindow &gameDisplay, Font &font1, bool &MainMenu, RectangleShape &start, Event &evnt)
    {
    gameDisplay.setMouseCursorVisible(true);


    Text starttext;
    starttext.setCharacterSize(100);
    starttext.setFont(font1);
    starttext.setString("DODGE");
    starttext.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    starttext.setStyle(Text::Bold);

    FloatRect starttextRect = starttext.getLocalBounds();
    starttext.setOrigin(starttextRect.width / 2, starttextRect.height / 2);
    starttext.setPosition(Vector2f(1366 / 2.0f - 30, 768 - 700.0f));




    RectangleShape outlinetop(Vector2f(1366, 50));
    outlinetop.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    outlinetop.setPosition(0, 0);

    RectangleShape outlinebottom(Vector2f(1366, 50));
    outlinebottom.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    outlinebottom.setPosition(0, 718);

    RectangleShape outlineright(Vector2f(50, 768));
    outlineright.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    outlineright.setPosition(1316, 0);

    RectangleShape outlineleft(Vector2f(50, 768));
    outlineleft.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
    outlineleft.setPosition(0, 0);


    Text startbuttontext;
    startbuttontext.setFont(font1);
    startbuttontext.setCharacterSize(70);
    startbuttontext.setString("PLAY");
    startbuttontext.setFillColor(Color(255, 255, 255));

    FloatRect startbuttontextRect = starttext.getLocalBounds();
    startbuttontext.setOrigin(starttextRect.width / 2, startbuttontextRect.height / 2);
    startbuttontext.setPosition(Vector2f(1366 / 2.0f + 60 - 30, 768 - 480.0f)); 














    if (MainMenu == true)
    {
        Vector2f tempMouse(Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay));
        if (start.getGlobalBounds().contains(tempMouse) &&
            evnt.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed &&
            evnt.key.code == Mouse::Left)
        {
            MainMenu = false;

        }







        //mouseposx = (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).x);
        //mouseposy = (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).y);


        /*
            while (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).x > 1366 / 2.0 && Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).x < 1083)
                while (Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).y > 768 - 450 && Mouse::getPosition(gameDisplay).y < 868)
                    if (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left))
                        MainMenu = false;
                        */



        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
        {
            MainMenu = false;
            gameDisplay.close();

        }


        gameDisplay.draw(outlinebottom);
        gameDisplay.draw(outlineleft);
        gameDisplay.draw(outlineright);
        gameDisplay.draw(outlinetop);
        gameDisplay.draw(start);
        gameDisplay.draw(starttext);
        gameDisplay.draw(startbuttontext);
        gameDisplay.display();

    }



}

     };
```

things.h

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace sf;
using namespace std;
#pragma once
int RandomXpos = 0;

class Thing
{
public:
void thingspawn(RenderWindow &gameDisplay, int &enemystartx, int &enemystarty, int &enemywidth, int &enemyheight, RectangleShape &thing, int enemyspeed)
{
    thing.setFillColor(Color(255,255,255));
    if (thing.getPosition().y < 800)
        thing.move(0.0f, 0.4f);
    if (thing.getPosition().y >= 800)
    {
        RandomXpos = rand() % 1000;
        thing.setPosition(RandomXpos, -200);
    }

    }
   };
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "things.h"
#include "Main Menu.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;




int main()
{
//FreeConsole();
RenderWindow gameDisplay(VideoMode(1366, 768), "Game", Style::Fullscreen);
gameDisplay.clear();
int enemystarty = -200;
int enemystartx = 300;
int enemyheight = 30;
int enemywidth = 300;
int enemyspeed = 0.3;
int enemycount = 1;
int dodged = 0;
int blockcolor = 0;
bool MainMenu = true;


Font font1;
if (!font1.loadFromFile("OCRAEXT.ttf"))
{
    //error...
}

RectangleShape start(Vector2f(400, 100));
start.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 0));
start.setOutlineThickness(20);
start.setOutlineColor(Color(255, 255, 255));

FloatRect startRect = start.getLocalBounds();
start.setOrigin(startRect.width / 2, startRect.height / 2);
start.setPosition(Vector2f(1366 / 2.0f, 768 - 450.0f));

/*
RectangleShape player(Vector2f(200, 50));
player.setFillColor(Color(0, 0, 255));
player.setPosition(400, 700);
*/

Texture playertexture;
if (!playertexture.loadFromFile("whiter_arrow.jpg"))
{
    //error...
}

Sprite player;
player.setTexture(playertexture);
player.setPosition(300, 600);

RectangleShape thing(Vector2f(enemywidth, enemyheight));
thing.setPosition(300, -200);


Event evnt;







while (gameDisplay.isOpen())
{

    while (gameDisplay.pollEvent(evnt))
    {
        switch (evnt.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            gameDisplay.close();
        case Event::KeyPressed:
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
                gameDisplay.close();

        }

    }



    main_menu object;
    object.startmenu(gameDisplay, font1, MainMenu, start, evnt);


    while (MainMenu == false)
    {
        gameDisplay.setMouseCursorVisible(false);

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::D))
            if (player.getPosition().x < 1200)
            {
                player.move(0.3f, 0.0f);
            }

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::A))
            if (player.getPosition().x > 50)
            {
                player.move(-0.3f, 0.0f);
            }
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q))
            gameDisplay.close();


        Thing thingobject;
        thingobject.thingspawn(gameDisplay, enemystartx, enemystarty, enemywidth, enemyheight, thing, enemyspeed);

        //collision detection
        if (player.getPosition().y <= thing.getPosition().y)
            if (player.getPosition().x == thing.getPosition().x)
                gameDisplay.close();


        gameDisplay.clear();
        gameDisplay.draw(player);
        gameDisplay.draw(thing);
        gameDisplay.display();

    }



    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do 2D collision detection between sets of objects ("do any of these objects touch each other") and that's beyond the scope of this question.  What you seem to be asking is much simpler: "do two 2D rectangles touch?".  Let's assume you have rectangles r1 and r2, then you can use:

```
collision = r1.x <= r2.x + r2.width && 
   r2.x <= r1.x + r1.width &&
   r1.y <= r2.y + r2.height && 
   r2.y <= r1.y + r1.height;
```

It is also worth noting that in games, you must allow for the possibility of the move increment being too large because of object velocity vs frame rate, allowing objects to appear to move through each other.  You can compensate by building bounding rectangles that encompass the before/after positions of both objects and testing that first, before diving into more complex calculations involving the intersection of the swept-through-time volumes.

Comment: thank yo, I have managed to work out a way to create a Collison detection without using a bounding box but thanks :3

Answer (score 0):

There is SFML way to do the collision, it will work for your case.

you can do it like this:

```
if ( player.getGlobalBounds().intersects(thing.getGlobalBounds()) )
{
      // player and thing is collided! do something
}
```

@**Wheezil**'s answer is the standard way to do it, for axis-aligned object like your case. it's better to implement it yourself so you know how it happens :)